# error reading MIDI files into program

Tags: standards, midi, file-type

I have a midi file which was generated using MuseScore. It plays well in Windows Media Player, but causes my midi reading program to crash. I've been using the following links to help me: [MIDI specification](http://www.oktopus.hu/imgs/MANAGED/Hangtechnikai_tudastar/The_MIDI_Specification.pdf) and [Mobilefish MIDI Guide](http://www.mobilefish.com/tutorials/midi/midi_quickguide_specification.html), the second one primarily.

```
4d 54 68 64 = MThd
00 00 00 06 = Header length of 6
00 01 = Track format 1
00 02 = two tracks
01 e0 = 480 delta-ticks per quarter note

4d 54 72 6b = MTrk
00 00 00 86 = length of 0x86
00 ff 58 04 04 02 18 08 = time signature
00 ff 59 02 00 00 = key signature
00 c0 00 = program change (channel 1)
02 b0 07 64 = control mode change (channel 1)
02 0a = running status
40 02 = running status
5b 1e = running status
02 5d = running status
1e ac 78 90 = Aftertouch event (channel 13, not really applicable in this context)
3e 50 = running status
83 5f 3e = delta time (83 5f) and 3e, which is not a status byte
(more bytes for context): 00 01 40 50
```

What exists in the MIDI standard that I've overlooked here?

Comment: Is it your own midi reading program? And you expect us to be more capable than your program by only supplying the input to figure out what went wrong in your program? I'm flattered by your confidence...

Comment: @rene Yes, it is my own. What input should I add in order to make this community more capable than my program? I can say that I've been following this: [MIDI Specification](http://www.oktopus.hu/imgs/MANAGED/Hangtechnikai_tudastar/The_MIDI_Specification.pdf), but this link could be precisely the problem (because it may be incomplete). And yes, I am confident enough to believe that a community of hundreds of thousands knows the answer.

Comment: I just realized that this actually could be running status. Does running status have delta times? And if so, is it required to have a delta time preceding the data bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question, which I wrote, is completely flawed, and I'm sorry to those people who tried to help me; I must have copied the output from Notepad++ incorrectly. However, for those who may run into the same issues that I did, I'll write an answer to this question.

Whenever running status is used, it is **always** preceded by a delta time. For those who may see guides that say otherwise, such as this one, http://www.blitter.com/~russtopia/MIDI/~jglatt/tech/midispec/run.htm, know that the information on these is completely misleading.

For example:

```
00 90 7F 7F
7F 00
50 7F
50 00
```

This is wrong.

However, this is the correct version:

```
00 90 7F 7F
81 00 7F 00
00 50 7F
81 00 50 00
```

This is clearly preceded by a delta time.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, running status still requires a variable time delta to be specified, so even if the two events happen at the same time there would still be a `00` byte proceeding the running status. However, with that in mind the aftertouch event in your above dump would lack any time offset, so I'm stumped.